# Remove far right margin on gallery box

Tags: html, css, gallery

Can you, please, help me to remove the far right margin from my boxes?
I am trying to use the `::after` pseudo element in CSS but it doesn't seem to work. (http://jsfiddle.net/ve0Laa8f/)

```
<div class="content-wrap">
<div class="content-center-wrap">
<div class="index-cats-wrap"></div>
<div class="index-cats-wrap"></div>
<div class="index-cats-wrap"><p>test</div>
</div>  
</div>  

.content-center-wrap{
    width:960px;
    height:auto;
    min-height:400px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:#fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top:40px;
    padding-bottom:40px;
}

.index-cats-wrap{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:298px;
    height:400px;
    margin-right:20px;
    border:1px solid #95a5a6;
}

.index-cats-wrap::after{
    margin-right:0px;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/ve0Laa8f/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [:last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) css selector.

```
.index-cats-wrap:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ve0Laa8f/5/